# Amazon redshift query planner

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm facing a situation with Amazon Redshift that I haven't been able to explain to myself yet. Query planner seems not to be able to handle same table in subquery of two derived tables in a join.

I have essentially three tables, Source_A, Source_B, Target_1, Target_2 and a query like

```
SELECT a,b,c,d FROM 
(
  SELECT a,b FROM Source_A where date > (SELECT max(date) FROM Target_1)
)     
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT c,d FROM Source_B where date > (SELECT max(date) FROM Target_2)
)
ON Source_A.a = Source_B.c
```

The query works fine as long as tables Target_1 and Target_2 are different tables. If I change the query so that Target_2 = Target_1, something happens. After the change, the query starts to take about 10 times longer time. And when I look at the performance monitor I can see that all this extra time is taken so that only the Leader Node is active.

When I take EXPLAIN of both options I see practically no difference in the output. All the steps are the same. But the is the difference that the EXPLAIN takes seconds in one and almost half an hour with the other one where the Target tables are the same.

So to summarise what I think I have observed is -- that on join, if I use same table in a subquery of each derived tables, the query planner goes nuts.

Comment: When you use subqueries to join same table, Redshift will not respect the dist key/ sort key and acts on the data extracted individually which is not optimal for joining as the data is displaced from the physical permanent space to temporary space and needs to be redistributed to be able to join on. From the given query I dont see a reason for using sub queries as you are not doing any aggregation or some thing that needs sub query. Make sure you collect stats on taget_1 and target_2 and source_a and source_b are vacuumed and stats on.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The example query is just an example. The most simple example I could come up with where I was able to reproduce the problem, but you are right that of course the query as is is just silly. Is there a reason why redshift doesn't do it the same for same table as it does it for two different tables? The difference is quite significant. Not a real problem, but I'm very curious.

Comment: Optimizer plans to extract data out of each given sub query and stores it in unsorted, random fashion which is not suitable to be used straight away with out resorting and redistributing according to the external join. It will not respect the dist keys, because once a sub query's output comes out it is not going to be a physical permanent table with different skew based on internal filter.